# Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin

Tags: angular, api, model-view-controller, http-post, same-origin-policy

I have a angular application , The client side post functionality cannot call the server Api post method.
Follwing Error display on Console

**":64736/api/Tool/SaveBookMark:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
:4200/#/envision/maps/google:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:64736/api/Tool/SaveBookMark' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."**

Client Side : angular 5

```
    const endpoint = this._api.saveBookMark;
let body = JSON.stringify(bookmarkModel);
return this.http.post(endpoint, body, this._api.getJsonOptions())
    .map(this._api.extractData)
    .catch(this._api.handleError);
```

Server Side : Mvc Api

```
[HttpPost]
    public string SaveBookMark(BookmarkModel bookmarkModel)
    {
        string res = string.Empty;
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your WebApiConfig.cs file add:

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
     config.EnableCors();
  }
```